# What are the obstacles to for instantaneous deposits?

Tags: deposits

To add a bank account to Venmo, the user provides bank account number and Venmo makes two small deposits into the account.  The user must verify that they have access to the account by indicating the amounts to Venmo.

Venmo indicated they had made two small deposits into my account and indicated these amounts will manifest themselves tomorrow:

- Is there any technical, regulation, or security reasons why the Venmo test transaction can not be completed within seconds?

The context is for American banks.

Comment: @yoozer8 that's the exact question I was looking for... :)

Comment: @yoozer8 Thanks for the thoughtful questionn.  I suppose it would if the Venmo transaction is an ACH transaction.  I literally do not know and seek to understand.

Comment: @gatorback Venmo has to first verify your access to the account via the two micropayments, and they go via ACH.

Comment: If you use Zelle, it happens within 10 seconds. This is because Zelle is a trusted online money transfer that most banks consciously joined. Venmo is a competition.